# Swagger UI - not displaying fields for some properties

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Is there a way to tell swagger to used the UI fields instead of a Json.
I have a property tat is a List of class that have a List of another class inside

[image]

This is the class that I am using as parameters in the API endpoint.

```
    public class LevelConfigurationSave
    {
        [Required]
        public string HomePlanId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LevelId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public LevelConfiguration Data { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class LevelConfiguration
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("configuration")] public ConfigurationCanvas Configuration { get; set; } = new();

        [JsonPropertyName("images")] public List<FloorPlanItem> Images { get; set; } = new();
    }


    public class FloorPlanItem
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("text")] public string Text { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonPropertyName("items")]
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();
    }
    
    public class Item
    {
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Always)]
        public IFormFile NewImageFile { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("src")]
        public string Src { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("visible")]
        public bool Visible { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonPropertyName("draggable")]
        public bool Draggable { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonPropertyName("userCanSelect")]
        public bool UserCanSelect { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonPropertyName("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; } = "";

        [JsonPropertyName("y")]
        public float Y { get; set; } = 0;

        [JsonPropertyName("x")]
        public float X { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class ConfigurationCanvas
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("width")] public decimal Width { get; set; } = 0;

        [JsonPropertyName("height")] public decimal Height { get; set; } = 0;

        [JsonPropertyName("autoScaleUp")]
        public bool AutoScaleUp { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

This is what I am looking to see for this property

[image]